# WP SEO by Yoast - How to change og:image size?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, yoast

I want to change the og:image that Yoast SEO generates, to some custom height and width (eg 1200x630) because I'm uploading very large images. I've tried adding this code in functions.php but doesn't work. Please help

```
function add_share_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size( 'facebook-share', 1200, 630, true );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_share_image_sizes' );

function set_yoast_facebook_share_image_size() {
    return 'facebook-share';
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_image_size', 'set_yoast_facebook_share_image_size' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a parameter.

```
function add_share_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size( 'facebook-share', 1200, 630, true );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_share_image_sizes' );

function set_yoast_facebook_share_image_size($img_size) {
    return 'facebook-share';
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_image_size', 'set_yoast_facebook_share_image_size' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoast has a filter to not handle images for og:image for 2Mb max. so you can update that by using a filter. Please add this code in your themes functions.php file.

```
// Increase image size for Yoast.
add_filter( 'wpseo_image_image_weight_limit', $n( 'filter_yoast_image_weight' ), 20 );

function filter_yoast_image_weight( $size ) {
return 20971520; // 20MB. 
}
```